# How to view pdf document in browser (ie, chrome, ff,safari)?

Tags: sharepoint, pdf, sharepoint-2010

I have a document library in SharePoint 2010. Is it possible to click an item in the document library and have a web part render the pdf file? If yes, how would you go by configuring it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with a content editor web part.  See the steps listed here:

http://manish-sharepoint.blogspot.com/2008/05/showing-pdf-document-content-in.html

Comment: Thank you Chris for the link but it wont work as the pdf is hard coded. I want that to change based on user's selection. For example, I have thousands of files in a library. User will select an item or record from the doc lib and pdf will render in a webpart.

Comment: If you have the library and the web part on the same page, and you want this to occur without posting back, then you could use javascript - see this link: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/hu-HU/sharepointdevelopment/thread/40b756f3-64dd-473d-aa5b-c8b3695de286

Comment: You could also have a handler on the list item and have the client-side link event kick off a javascript or jquery method that finds your content editor web part and changes what document it is pointing to.

Comment: (The enter button keeps posting my comment...sorry about that)  Finally, you could have a custom button in the ribbon or a custom action on the library item that does what you need.  There are a lot of options...if you need something more specific, I'll need a bit more info.